# Letra vocal y no vocal

Tags: c

buen día
tengo una duda sobre si se puede cambiar la estructura condicional de if por otra

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{


    char letra;

    printf("Digita una letra:");
    scanf("%c",&letra);

    if ( letra == 'a' || letra == 'A' ||
         letra == 'e' || letra == 'E' ||
         letra == 'i' || letra == 'I' ||
         letra == 'o' || letra == 'O' ||
         letra == 'u' || letra == 'U' )
        printf( "\n   ES UNA VOCAL" );
    else
        printf( "\n   NO ES UNA VOCAL" );

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Podrias hacer un switch y el resultado seria exactamente el mismo.

Comment: ya lo había intentado antes pero me sale error al compilar ya que el switch usa enteros numéricos

Comment: eh... no.. porque?

Comment: en el programa uso caracteres en letras y se debe introducir una letra no una opción y por lo tanto el programa no ejecutaría

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/switch_statement_in_c.htm mira ahi

Comment: Los literales de caracter tambien son números enteros y funcionan perfectamente dentro de un switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si te interesa una solución que evita usar un `switch`, ahí te la dejo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int esVocal(int c) {
  return (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u');
}

int main(void) {
    char letra;

    printf("Digita una letra:");
    letra = (char)fgetc(stdin);
    letra = tolower(letra);

    printf("%s UNA VOCAL", (esVocal(letra))? "ES": "NO ES");

    return 0;
}
```

Es prácticamente lo mismo que está en la respuesta de [Diego Avila](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/248037/4499), solo que uso el [operador ternario (`?:`)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operador_ternario#Asignaci%C3%B3n_condicional) de C.

Si te fijas he cambiado la llamada a `scanf` por [`fgetc`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgetc.htm), llamar a `scanf` por un solo caracter no es tan eficiente.

Saludos :)

Comment: sin duda muy simple la respuesta, solo que hace falta el cierre del parentesis en el return de "esVocal"

Comment: Arregladillo :)

Answer (score 1):

Saludos puedes realizar algo así:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char letra;
    printf("Digita una letra:");
    scanf("%c",&letra);
    char vocalConvertida = tolower(letra);
    switch(vocalConvertida) {

    case ('a')  :
      printf( "\n   ES UNA VOCAL" );
      break; 

    case ('e')  :
      printf( "\n   ES UNA VOCAL" );
      break; 

    case ('i')  :
      printf( "\n   ES UNA VOCAL" );
      break; 

    case ('o')  :
      printf( "\n   ES UNA VOCAL" );
      break; 


    case ('u')  :
      printf( "\n   ES UNA VOCAL" );
      break; 

    default :
        printf( "\n   NO ES UNA VOCAL" );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

si te fijas tambien lo que hice fue convertir a minusculas una vez ingresada la letra para evitar tantas condiciones, el resultado seria:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Comment: A pesar de que resuelve el problema, no es la forma más eficiente de hacerlo, el `switch`, claro.

Comment: con un solo printf y un solo break alcanzaba :(

Comment: seria bueno que propongas tu solución @gbianchi para dar la mejor respuesta ..!!

Answer (score 1):

La solucion que diego da es correcta. Sin embargo, en C, el código del `switch` se puede simplificar mucho más.

Como cada `case` cae al siguiente, salvo que exista un break, y tomando la licencia de su código, se puede simplificar a lo siquiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char letra;
    printf("Digita una letra:");
    scanf("%c",&letra);
    char vocalConvertida = tolower(letra);
    switch(vocalConvertida) {
    case ('a')  :
    case ('e')  :
    case ('i')  :
    case ('o')  :
    case ('u')  :
      printf( "\n   ES UNA VOCAL" );
      break; 
    default :
        printf( "\n   NO ES UNA VOCAL" );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

En este caso, sea cual sea el caso verdadero, solo va a ejecutar el ultimo printf.

Hay que tener en cuenta que los dos códigos hacen exactamente lo mismo, solo que este ultimo, se ahorra bytes de compilación.

Comment: Me siento bien viendote responder aquí :')

Comment: genial @gbianchi buena argumentación ..!!

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma de hacerlo es utilizando el método **`strchr`** de la librería ***`string.h`*** para tratar de simular un `indexOf`. Con un método `indexOf` puedes obtener la posición de la primera ocurrencia del valor especificado.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int indexOf(char * cadena, int caracter){
    int indice = -1;

    char *ptr = strchr(cadena, caracter);

    if(ptr != NULL) {
       indice = ptr - cadena;
    }

    return indice;
}

int main() {
    char vocales[] = "aeiouAEIOU";
    char letra;

    printf("Digita una letra:");
    scanf("%c",&letra);

    if(indexOf(vocales, letra) > -1) {
        printf("\n   ES UNA VOCAL");
    }
    else {
        printf("\n   NO ES UNA VOCAL");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

El método `indexOf` devolverá un entero mayor o igual `0` en caso de que encuentre alguna coincidencia, en caso contrario retornara `-1`.

> [strchr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/): Localiza la primera aparición de caracteres en la cadena.
>   Retorna un puntero en la primera aparición del carácter a buscar.